# CSS not linking when uploaded to a website

Tags: html, css

Can any of you spot an error here?? If there is one... I'm going bananas here... CSS page is not linking with html when uploaded to server. And W3 validation says "No Character Encoding Found! Falling back to UTF-8." ???

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Text</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Another text">
  <meta name="author" content="Content Text">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><!-- About page Services -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!-- H1, h2 -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Molengo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><!-- p -->
  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <link href="css/grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <link href="css/style3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Do you need

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

before starting css files?

```
<?php include('inc/header.php'); ?>
<div id="index" class="container">
  <div class="container">
```

That ok to do isn't it? this include line is top of the page and above all other content

Comment: Try accessing the CSS files using your browser. Do you see their Contents?

Comment: Which CSS is giving you the problem?

Comment: I think all of them. None of them are displaying for some reason. I'm out of ideas why... :(

Comment: Close your first meta tags with />

Comment: @Danko That shouldn't be a Problem when using HTML 5.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you in a position to monitor this with a tool like Fiddler to make sure these are getting to the browser?

Comment: Does your server serve the CSS files with `text/css` as the MIME type?

Comment: You see with Fiddle I would have to pull the whole page in it.

Comment: What tool did you use to validate this? I have put your source code in the validator on http://validator.w3.org/ and it says its valid.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but are those CSS files *actually* in the css subfolder relative to the HTML in question?

Comment: What does this mean? "You see with Fiddle I would have to pull the whole page in it."

Comment: This is the way my folders are: img(Folder) css(folder) inc(folder) index.php(seperate file)

Comment: Yes, but are the CSS files actually in there? Can you load them into the browser? And are the names identical, including the casing?

Comment: Just validated the whole document on w3 schools validator... Still same issue..

Comment: Yes loaded every single css file through browser all visible

Comment: @Tauciokas, at least with my feeble brain, I don't see enough here to specifically diagnose.  If I were you I'd fire up Fiddler (or something like Charles on Linux) and take a look at the actual conversations going on between your browser and the web server.

Comment: Can you supply a link to your site so this insane comment thread can stop?

Comment: OK, OK, I give up. What's the URI?

Comment: Can you supply a link to your site so this insane comment thread can stop? – Adam 1 min ago Hahaha.. Yeah.. :)

Comment: www.pixelweblab.com/index.php is not a PHP file!!!

Comment: How come?? its index.php

Comment: So its the server then>?

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't mean it's treated as such on the server. The evidence says not.

Comment: Yes. Contact your host.

Comment: Right. But first, accept Adam's answer. Oh, by the way, are the stylesheet links that you show in your question, actually in the file `http://www.pixelweblab.com/inc/header.php`? In the subdirectory?

Comment: @Adam your answer is not showing up for me

Comment: Oh, nothing. I see you already adjusted the paths to the CSS files.

Comment: @MrLister - I shouldn't have made it an answer, it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well somebody answer it... :) I want to give it to somebody atleast... :)) Good work guys thx

Comment: @Adam just answer it :) again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index file is not getting parsed as php. 1) Did you give it a .php extension? 2) Does your server have php installed on it?